# Array is not array

Tags: javascript, json

I am running

```
var n = [];
jQuery.toJSON( n );
```

On one page I get `"[]"` on the other `""[]""`. On both pages I run the same jQuery version with a [toJson Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/).

In Firefox DOM I can see both arrays have the same function names, but ... different:

```
all     b(B, A)
any     j(B, A)

all     all(iterator, context)
any     any(iterator, context)
```

I guess there are some Array.prototype functions before my script. That causing the arrays to be different. I can't change the other code I have to somehow deal with this.

I tried `new Array()` and `jQuery.makeArray(n)`, still same result. I actually don't care that the arrays are not equal but how do I get the same JSON code for this? It's getting worse if I have strings in the array: `""[\"a\", \"b\"]""`

Comment: Any chance that you did turn it into JSON twice?

Comment: can you try console.dir(n) and see if there is any difference bt the two?

Comment: @Gumbo I don't see how if I just run `jQuery.toJSON([])`.

Comment: @ustun yes, I showed the difference in the second box. Same functions names but different implementions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra quotes are caused by the

```
Array.prototype.toJSON
```

function that is defined by the Prototype library and possibly other libraries as well. This function is called by `jQuery.toJSON` (or JSON.Stringify() for that matter) and produces the extra quotes. If you would use

```
delete Array.prototype.toJSON // remove toJSON for all Arrays
//or
delete n.toJSON // remove toJSON for specific Array
```

before you do the `jQuery.toJSON`, that should work!

As another suggestion, it is better to use

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```

instead of `jQuery.toJSON`. It is supported natively in most browsers. If you want to be sure it works everywhere, use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js, it is the basis used for the `JSON.stringify()` function.

For `JSON.stringify()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON for more info.

Comment: I did, same problem. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: In what browser + situation do you get the extra quotes?

Comment: Hmm, JSON is meant for objects, not for arrays (although they are technically also objects). If you want to JSON-ify arrays, you should first create an object from that array, thén stringify... Could you try that?

Comment: `JSON.stringify( {a: ["test"]} );` => `"{"a":"[\"test\"]"}"`. The object is ok but the array is still wrong.

Comment: Arrays are not seen as objects, so you need to convert the array to an object (i.e. loop over the array and add elements to a newly created object). As you have it now, there's still an array *in* an object. You need to get rid of the array...

Comment: But I don't want an object, I need an array. According to [RFC 4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627) arrays are valid in JSON.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I think you use Prototype, which provides a toJSON function on Arrays. This function is called by JSON.Stringify() and produces the quotes. If you would use "delete Array.prototype.toJSON" before you do the stringify, it should work!

Comment: Thanks, I found a even better solution: `n.toJSON = null` works the same way but does not affect's other arrays. Maybe you can add that to your answer.

Comment: Yep that works too! Keep in mind though that you'll have to do that before the stringify of *any* Array instead of fixing it once and for all...

Comment: @PiTheNumber your solution worked for me as well. With only delete Array.prototype.toJSON it didn't

Answer (score 0):

My dirty hack for this is:

```
function cleanJson(s)
{
    if (s[0] == '"')
    {
        s = s.substring(1, s.length-1).replace(/\\"/g,'"');
    }
    return s;
}
```

Does the job, but I am still looking for a cleaner solution.